# Clojure functions within arithmetic expressions

Tags: clojure

How would one write the following ocaml expression in clojure:

```
fun x -> (f (x +. dx) -. f x) /. dx
```

I simplehearted tried the following expression, but that throws an exception:

```
(defn derivative [dx f]
  (fn [x] 
    (/ (- f [(+ x dx)] f [x]) dx)))

((derivative 0.01 (fn [x] (* x x))) 1)
```

java.lang.ClassCastException: ableitung$eval5058$fn__5059 cannot be cast to java.lang.Number
         Numbers.java:135 clojure.lang.Numbers.minus

Comment: I tried to translate the ocaml-example "The power of functions". And mixed the syntaxes of function-calls.

Answer (score 4):

You need to apply `f` which you do with `(f x y ..)`. You probably also shouldn't pass a single vector argument into `f`, although it's impossible to tell without the definition:

```
(defn derivative [dx f]
  (fn [x] 
    (/ (- (f (+ x dx)) (f x)) dx)))
```